# Make form elements disabled or readonly by wrapping them with something?

Tags: css, html, forms

Is it possible in an HTML form to mark several input elements as readonly or disabled by wrapping them with something?

I know you can set the form itself as disabled for example, but that of course disabled the whole form. I'm thinking something like:

```
<form>

    <input name="not-readonly">

    <div readonly="readonly">
        <input name="readonly-field-1">
        <input name="readonly-field-2">
    </div>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or could this be solved with CSS somehow? Or maybe only with Javascript?

Comment: Why not just disable the inputs? Why do you need a wrapper?

Comment: @Moobs The reason is that I don't have control over the generation of the input fields, only the group as a whole. I.e. I can't add the readonly attribute to each single field, but I can wrap the group with something.

Comment: You can disable a `fieldset` but not cross-browser by the looks of it

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered that as well. Doesn't seem to support the readonly attribute though... :/

Comment: Actually, you cannot set the form itself as disabled — `form` element doesn't have such attribute, only inputs and fieldset can be [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3:boolean-attribute-11).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know how to disable inputs in the regular way based on the fact that you have 34k rep.

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="something"/>
```

Easily done with jquery of course (example based on your markup)

```
$('div[readonly="readonly"]').find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

You can't actually disable an input with css, but you can fake a disabled input with css like:

```css
.fakeinput {
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #aaa;
  border: #999 1px solid;
  background: fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p class="fakeinput">Pretend Value</p>
```

Comment: That is correct :P But yeah, found a way to *disable* elements using a `fieldset` with the `disabled` attribute, but no readonly support. So seems I'll have to use some Javascript to solve it in this case :/

Comment: Maybe 34k rep in C++ development :D

Comment: Again.. WARNING! : not recommended - as 'disabled' form fields vales will not be passed in a post when you try to save. Instead - if there were values there read from the database - they will now e saved back to the database as '' - in other words - deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that you can *disable* a group of form elements using the [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) tag. However, it seems to be [slightly buggy in certain versions of IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Browser_compatibility). There also is no support for the `readonly` attribute, which unfortunately was the one I needed in this case... maybe it'll be added later?

```
<form>

    <input name="not-disabled">

    <fieldset disabled>
        <input name="disabled-field-1">
        <input name="disabled-field-2">
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: not recommended - as 'disabled' form fields vales will not be passed in a post when you try to save. Instead - if there were values there read from the database - they will now e saved back to the database as '' - in otherwords - deleted.

Answer (score -3):

javascript

```
document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true;
```

CSS

```
<INPUT NAME="realname" VALUE="Hi There" readonly>

<INPUT NAME="realname" VALUE="Hi There" disabled>
```

Comment: No explanation. JS irrelevant to the question and the rest of your answer. HTML code marked "CSS". HTML uppercase.